# Change the size of a users profile photo?

Tags: users, image-transforms, user-profile

I have a website where I am pulling a list of staff members from the Craft users. You can add individual fields to the users element, but it seems the image for the photo is incredibly small is size and lacking in quality.

Is there a way to change the size of the profile photo? Hopefully I can just apply an image transform on the user profile photo. Adding another field for a photograph seems redundant.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the answer on the Craft website under the [UserModel section](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/usermodel#getPhotoUrl):

> **getPhotoUrl( size )**
>
> Returns a URL to the user’s photo at a given size in pixels (defaults to 100). You can also pass in "original" if you want to get a non-resized photo back.

Although this does answer my question, I feel the behavior between handling this "asset" compared to an actual native asset is a little cumbersome, especially considering if I wanted to apply an image transformation on the original file.

Comment: Feel free to nuke my edit, I just figured I'd quote the docs since I had to visit to *see* the answer you referred to.

Comment: No way, thats a good edit. I will try to remember to do that from now on. Thank you for the edit Matt!