# How do I tell Craft not to automatically crop user profile images?

Tags: user-profile

When uploading user profile images, Craft forces you to crop it to a square. Is there a way to keep the images untouched instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a custom asset field for the users' profile images and hide the default one in the CP.

Here's a plugin to do this: [Control Panel CSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) by Lindsey D

Comment: Lol, actually I just posted this to the [question below yours](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/change-the-location-of-the-user-photos), but it fits here too. :D

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but I asked a similar question. I needed to grab the original size of the user uploaded images.

[Change the size of a users profile photo?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/change-the-size-of-a-users-profile-photo)

You can just use `getPhotoUrl('original')` when calling the images on the front end.

This doesn't give you an 'untouched' version of the image but Craft stores the original and makes it easy to call.

Comment: But this "original" is still the rectangularly cropped version of the original "original", Jason?

Comment: I will have to try that this afternoon, but I believe the original is the actual original and they crop it for the CP only.

Comment: I tried this already, you get the cropped version with the original quality.

Comment: Ahh, maybe a request to p&t to change this behavior. The other answer posted here is the same method I used for a staff listing.